# I am not able to receive same message which I am sending using SerialPort Class

Tags: c#, serial-port

#### C# Console Application

I am using **SerialPort** class to send/receive message using serial prot communication. Currently I am using Virtual COM Port software to create virtual COM ports in my machine.

#### What I wanted to achieve like following:

If I send : **Hello** Then I should receive: **Hello**

#### Problems

I am not able to receive same message. It is decode into some random any alphabets or special characters.

Instead of:

```
Hello
```

...I am getting:

```
Hiiii
```

or

```
H.....
```

or

```
H@@@@
```

I sending any random chars

You may see the result in the following screenshot. Here I am sending Hello but receiving some different chars.

I am using following code to listen DataReceive Event

```
private void Barcode_Received(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
            //#Reading barcode data which is comming from Instrument/Device/Beckman
                var serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;
                string data = serialPort.ReadExisting();
}
```

Here is the complete code where I am calling above event.

```
                serialPort = new SerialPort()
                {
                    PortName = "COM1",
                    ReadTimeout = 1500,
                    BaudRate = 9600,
                    DataBits = 8,
                    StopBits = StopBits.One,
                    Parity = Parity.None,

                    Handshake = configuration.Handshake,
                    DtrEnable = true, //Default is false
                    RtsEnable = true,  //Default is false
                    NewLine = Environment.NewLine,
                    //Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                };

                //Add Event Listener
                serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Barcode_Received);


                if (!serialPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    serialPort.Open();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Established!");
                Console.ReadLine();
                serialPort.Close();
```

**Note:**
For single char message it is working perfectly.

Comment: Ensure that both ends of the link are configured the same - baud, databits, parity, handshake etc.  What is `configuration.Handshake` in your example?  Be sure to set it to `Handshake.RequestToSend` and **not** `Handshake.None` or `Handshake.XOnXOff`.

Comment: Try to ASCIIEncode your text before sending it.

Comment: ...also reguarding your `DataReceived` handler, I'm assuming you have trimmed it prior to posting here.  Avoid doing anything CPU-intensive or _timely_ inside any form of data communication event handler whether it be serial ports or TCP.   Instead place the results into some form of _queue_ for later processing by a different worker thread thus allowing your event handler to exit ASAP.   Otherwise it can lead to data loss.

Comment: At the time of message sending I am using COM1 and while receiving COM2.

Comment: I am using Handshake.None. Going to check both  side configuration as you suggested. Thanks

Comment: Hi @MickyD, I have tried same configuration while send/receive both but still getting same kind or data error.

Comment: Did you set hardware flow control?   Pretty sure that is your issue.

Comment: @MickyD, Yes, while sending set as Handshake.RequestToSend and while receiving I have tried all 3 options one by one.

Comment: @MickyD - For single char message it is working fine only issue with multi chars message

Comment: @MickyD, At message sender end Handshake.RequestToSend configured and please for receiver side handshake value?